# How to make an alias for url in .htaccess

Tags: html, wordpress, alias

As in the title. I know, there are many topics about redirecting but any of them haven' t resolved my problem.

For example, I have site like this:

> http://example.com/?open=true

I would like to make an alias for this site:

> http://example.com/other-name

I' ve tried to rewrite it in .htaccess file but it isn't working properly.

Comment: In what way "it isn't working properly?"

Comment: The final url looked like: http://example.com/other-name?open=true

Answer (score 1):

In wordpress you don't need to change anything in .htaccess file you can just change alias or change url pattern of your website by

go to admin panel of wordpress->settings->permalinks

and select custom structure and add your own custom structure for url or you can use predefined structures  for more details about permalinks

please refer below link.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

I hope it will you :)

Comment: Well, you are right. Normally it's working but it's not resolving my problem. I have problemt with this question mark sign and everything what' s on right of it. It still show ' ..?open=true ' and I realy don't know how to change it ^^ Thanks for your answer:)